# dealing with DocPanel on Canvas and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create 3 columns (dock-able) on left side of window using XAML. This window used to be a Grid base now it should be Canvas so no more following code would work:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="1,1,7,0">
        </StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="one"  IsExpanded="True"/>
        <Expander Header="two" IsExpanded="True"/>
        <Expander Header="three"  IsExpanded="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

So I now I'm using  as container now instead. However, **One**, **Two** and **Three** are displayed on line line however, I need to have them vertically.

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto">
    <Expander Header="One" IsExpanded="True"/>
    <Expander Header="Two" IsExpanded="True"/>
    <Expander Header="Three" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

My goal is to create toolbar on left side of the window so these  will show some controls that user can drag and drop onto Canvas. I will appreciate it if you experts could give me some hints on this matter too.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for Visual studio like docking system.  try avalon dock

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

[image]

Comment: Wow I just noticed your comment. It is a very nice example and thanks for sharing it. Is it grid base or is it a canvas? long story short, I need to switch from grid to canvas and wondering if this would work on it.  Thank you

Comment: welll canvas doesn't support what you want for that you need to play with canvas inside grid we also need in previous project.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding what you want correctly, you'll want to add 'DockPanel.Dock="Top"' to all expanders but the last.